# Is the second, third, and nth standard deviation an established concept?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

Of course the first standard deviation is a measure that shows the level of variation among a set of values, and is of course derived by taking the sqrt of mean squared differences of the values to their mean.

But what if you needed to know the level of variation OF the variation of the set of values. This would be the second standard deviation, and would be derived by taking the sqrt of mean squared differences of the residuals to their standard deviation. And in the same way: the third, fourth, and nth standard deviation.

Comment: Are you dealing with the population or a sample?  If the former, are you saying $\sigma_1= \sqrt{\frac1n\sum(x_i-\mu)^2}$ and $\sigma_2= \sqrt{\frac1n\sum(|x_i-\mu|-\sigma_1)^2}$ or something else?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I have in mind! We can go with population, it translates the same way with sample

Comment: The [moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)) of a probability distribution, which generalize the mean and variance, are a more common way to describe "higher-order" information about a distribution's shape.